# Bar on a fermion field, arrows on fermion lines and particle-particle nature of fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model

This question is about the use of bar on a fermionic field in a Lagrangian, the use of arrows on external fermion lines and the particle-antiparticle nature of a fermion.

For illustration of my question, I will use the following the charged-current interaction of the Standard model:

$$\mathcal{L}_{cc} 
             = ie_{W}\big[W_{\mu}^{+}(\bar{\nu}_{m}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})e_{m} + V_{mn}\bar{u}_{m}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})d_{n})\\
            + W_{\mu}^{-}(\bar{e}_{m}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})\nu_{m} + (V^{\dagger})_{mn}\bar{d}_{m}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})u_{n})\big].$$

---

1. What is the physical consequence of having a bar on one fermionic field in a Lagrangian? For example, the first term in the Lagrangian has a bar over the neutrino field $\nu$ while the third term has a bar over the electron field $e$. Is the role of the bar simply to ensure Lorentz invariance or is there some physical consequence to, say, the $W^{+}$-boson-to-lepton-decay due to having a bar on the neutrino field $\nu$ and not on the electron field $e$ in the first term of the Lagrangian?
2. How does the particle-antiparticle nature of a fermion show itself in the Lagrangian? Is it through the bar on a fermion field, or through the charge-conjugation operator, or ...?

Comment: What do you mean "the physical consequence"? You can't even write *down* a Lagrangian without using a fermion with a bar, since the Lagrangian must be scalar - how else are you going to get a scalar out of two fermions? What do you mean by "particle-antiparticle nature of a fermion"? How does, for comparison, the particle-antiparticle nature of a complex scalar "show itself"?

Comment: By physical consequence, I mean if the bar over a fermion field plays any role in whether the fermion field is a particle or an antiparticle.

Comment: I do not know how the particle-antiparticle nature of a complex scalar field shows itself in the lagrangian?